# How to use Rottentomatoes.com API

Tags: android, api, rotten-tomatoes

I want use **[rottentomatoes.com](http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/)** API in my `Android` application. I have registered and confirmed my email address and they sent me an API Key, but when I use this key, it shows me this error :

{"error":"Account Inactive"}

How can I activate my account and use this API?

Comment: ... and? simply ask **them** what to do.

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi, my account is not active but i confirm it. how can i active this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accortding to their help forum you need to send an email to API-admin@flixster-inc.com with the following information.

How are you planning on using the data?
How are you using the API in your app/website? Is the data being cached?
Provide mocks of the app/website with the RT API integration following the Brand Guidelines.
What is the estimated number of monthly users?
Provide a country of origin for your app/website.
Your API Username and Email address

See here for help on the matter: 
`http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/forum/read/188558`

Comment: Apply for access: https://developer.fandango.com/rotten_tomatoes